# DBeaver database export not exporting foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, migration, dbeaver, schema-migration

I have DBeaver 23.1.0 on Windows.

I want to export tables (PostgreSQL) from Database A to Database B, including foreign keys.
What I found out was to mark all tables from Database A -> Right click -> Export Data -> Database table(s) -> Target container Database B.
The tables and data are migrated, but the foreign keys not.

When I export the data as SQL INSERT, no CREATE TABLE is created in the sql.

I want to solve the task with just DBeaver, not with command line tools like `pg_dump`.

Any ideas?